# Count and display ways to climb staircase java

Tags: java, algorithm

I wrote some code to count and also print the number of ways to climb a given staircase with `n` steps.

It is only possible to climb 1 or 2 stairs at a time. I know this is a known interview question and I have some code I wrote to share with you.

The problem is i am missing a lot of sequences. Can you please review and help me understand what logic I am missing? Thanks for your help

My code:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package prep;

/**
 * @author rohandalvi
 *
 */
public class generateAllPermutations {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    static int totalCounter = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int numberOfStairs = 10;
        int countSoFar = 0;
        String path = "";
        for(int i=1;i<3;i++){
            path = ""+i;
            displayAllPerms(numberOfStairs, i, path);
        }
        System.out.println("Total combinations found "+totalCounter);
    }

    public static void displayAllPerms(int n,int countSoFar,String s){
        if(countSoFar > n) return;
        else if(countSoFar < n){
            for(int i=1;i<3;i++){
                s+=" "+i;
                countSoFar+=i;
                displayAllPerms(n, countSoFar, s);
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Found combination "+s);
            totalCounter++;
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Result:

```
Found combination 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
Found combination 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
Found combination 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
Found combination 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1
Found combination 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
Found combination 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2
Found combination 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1
Found combination 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2
Found combination 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1
Found combination 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1
Found combination 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2
Found combination 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1
Found combination 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1
Found combination 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1
Found combination 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2
Found combination 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1
Found combination 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1
Found combination 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1
Found combination 1 1 2 1 2 1 2
Found combination 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
Found combination 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
Found combination 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
Found combination 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1
Found combination 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1
Found combination 2 1 1 1 2 1 2
Found combination 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1
Found combination 2 1 1 2 1 1 2
Found combination 2 1 1 2 1 2 1
Found combination 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1
Found combination 2 1 2 1 1 1 2
Found combination 2 1 2 1 1 2 1
Found combination 2 1 2 1 2 1 1
```

Basically, I am missing combinations like:

```
2 2 2 2 2
```

And a lot more combinations, basically all starting with 2 2

Comment: Can you use the `Collections` and `List` frameworks? Those would make the solution I am writing easier.

Comment: Sure you can do that, but it would be better for me to understand what's wrong with my code if you can follow the same pattern I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your recursion method `displayAllPerms`, you are modifying the local values of `countSoFar` and `s`:

```
s+=" "+i;
countSoFar+=i;
```

You should instead pass the new values like this:

```
for(int i=1;i<3;i++){
    displayAllPerms(n, countSoFar + i, s + " " + i);
}
```

This leaves the local values of `countSoFar` and `s` in the current method unchanged for the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: I just tested this out on Ideone (same idea as you) surprisingly does not work.

Comment: I just noticed that `s` has the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

Let me start by stating a recursive approach for this problem, that I suspect you have taken. Then, I will move on to the code.

Ways to climb 3 steps = [ways to climb 2 steps] + [ways to climb 1 step].

Generalizing, ways to climb `n` steps = [ways to climb `n-1` steps] + [ways to climb `n-2` steps].

**If you haven't noticed, this is the Fibonacci pattern (alternative solution is to simply return the `n+1`<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number; try it out!).**

```
public int getWays(int n) {
    if(n <= 1) return n;

    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; (i <= 2 && i <= n); i++)
        result += getWays(n-i);
    return result;
}

// Usage:
int steps = 4;
getWays(steps + 1);    // 5 ways
```

Now, if you want to look at the combinations taken. I am taking a slightly different approach that I think is more intuitive.

```
public static void waysToReachN(int currentValue, int n, List<Integer> pathSoFar) {
    if(currentValue == n) {
        System.out.println(pathSoFar);
        return;
    } else if(currentValue > n) {
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= 2 ; i++) {
        // add step
        pathSoFar.add(i);

        // recurse
        waysToReachN(currentValue + i, n, pathSoFar);

        // remove step
        pathSoFar.remove(pathSoFar.size()-1);
    }
}

// Usage:
int currentValue = 0, n = 4;
waysToReachN(currentValue, n, new ArrayList<Integer());
```

So, we had found that there were 5 ways to climb 4 stairs. The ways are,

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 2]
```

Please let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: how did you come up with this recursive code?  I have a hard time coming up with recursive code.  the solution is very impressive.

Comment: One thing I may add to your code is that check if current value is greater than N before calling recursive function.  This will avoid unnecessary call.

Comment: I've modified the code for any random steps like 1, 2 & 4 or 1, 3, 5 or even more steps. Nice idea. up voted.